# On and Off Button on Arduino

Tags: c++, button, arduino, servo, arduino-ultra-sonic

I'm back with another non-homework related question. I'm playing with an arduino with my brother, and we're trying to attach a button so that when its pressed, his sensor stays on and does what it has to do. When its pressed again it'll do nothing and turn off. Right now when the button is held down it stays on, but when its unpressed it stays off. We're trying to make something that'll continuously take pictures when its thrown off a building. It'll stop with the ultra-sonic sensor reads <= 5.  I can't throw myself off the roof top while holding the button XD It's a 2 pin button. 
Here's the code of what we have right now:

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;
const int buzzer = 11;
const int ledPin = 13;
const int buttonPin = 2;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
int safetyDistance;

#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // twelve servo objects can be created on most boards 
int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

void setup() {
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);// Sets the echoPin as an Input
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
myservo.attach(8);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
}


void loop() {
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH);

// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

// Calculating the distance
distance= duration*0.034/2;

safetyDistance = distance;

if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
{
if (safetyDistance <= 5){
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
else{
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  for(pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 20) // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(10);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=0; pos-=2)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(10);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
}
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
Serial.print("Distance: ");
Serial.println(distance);
}
```

Now, what we're having trouble with is, I understand that there has to be states for the button. But as we were scouring the internet for help we came across terms like debouncing and we just don't understand what that means. We're so close to finally finishing our mini project. The servo is moving fine, the ultrasonic sensor works well. We just need help figuring out this button. Any advice and help would be appreciated as we're both scratching our heads on this one. Thank you!!

--Zane

Answer (score 0):

Normal buttons, like they are used in most project, are doing nothing else but pressing two electrical contacts together, when it is pressed. But - because it's a mechanical action with limited velocity - the level on the pin doesn't simply rise from LOW to HIGH (or vice versa). Instead it changes it's level in the moment the button gets pressed a few times, until the final level is reached. This variation is to fast for a human to see (for example with an attached LED), but slow enough for a microcontroller like the arduino taking notice. So often you have to make sure, that it's really only one button press, even if the level changes a few times in a row. Mostly it is sufficient to add a small timeout, where the button presses aren't recognized by your code (for example 50 ms), or checking a second time for the state of the button after this period. You can check the corresponding [Arduino page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) for an official example of debouncing.

In your code you are only checking directly the state of the button, which is why it turns off, when you release the button. I would try something like this:

```
boolean program_state = false;
unsigned long debounce_time = 50;
unsigned long debounce_time_stamp=0;

void loop(){
    // ultasound measuring code
    if(digitalRead(buttonPin) && debounce_time_stamp - millis() > debounce_time){
        program_state=!program_state;
        debounce_time_stamp = millis();
    }

    if(program_state){
        // distance checking and servo code
    }
}
```

This check - when the button is pressed - if enough time has been bygone since the last recognized press (the amount of time can be adjusted with the variable `debounce_time`). When a valid press is recognized, the `program_state` variable is toggled to change the state between the two modes (On and Off).
Notice that with this the code is unresponsive for the time the servo needs to finish one sequence. If you want to have code, that is more responsive, you should consider using the button as an external interrupt (for this look at the examples on the correspondig Arduino page).